# multiple hexagon shape buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-drawable

I'm trying to create a design with multiple hexagon shape buttons.I'm able to create a single hexagon button, but in my case i have a list of items which need to be shown in a design pattern like below.

[image]

if such list design is possible through `RecyclerView` that would be much better.

Comment: fixed number of buttons or changing?

Comment: well currently the list is fixed but it can be change in future.

Comment: if they are fixed number you directly use Imagebutton

Comment: I know i can use image in this case but im worried about the placing and spacing of the buttons

Comment: User relative layout make your OPD buttons centerIn parent true and then relative adjust all other buttons

Comment: Hey bro, User similar images and place it using Relative layout, If you not able to create same please let me know I will design it for you. Its very Simple

Comment: Do you need them to change colour when the user presses on them?

Comment: @Eselfar no that's not required.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A bit tricky but here is how i solved it.
Have a recyclerView like below

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/hexa_rcv"
                android:layout_margin=""@dimen/hexa_dp""
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

make 2 folders inside res  "values-sw360dp" and "values-sw400dp". create dimens.xml in both the folders. dimens.xml inside values-sw360dp should have

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="margin_16_dp">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="hexa_dp">25dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

dimens.xml inside values-sw400dp should have

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="margin_16_dp">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="hexa_dp">55dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

And one item for the recyclerView like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tv_1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="ICU_HDW"
    android:background="@drawable/hexagon"/>
```

Next have a get the reference of recyclerView and set GridaLayoutManager with column size as 3. make every 5th item's span size as 2(so that 4th item will have span size 1 and 5th item will have size 2 hence both together will complete the row and next item will be placed in next row)

I have used kotlin here you can convert to java

```
    RecyclerView hexaRcv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.hexa_rcv);
    GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
    manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            int size = 1;
            if ((position + 1) % 5 == 0){
                size = 2;
            }
            return size;
        }
    });

    hexaRcv.setLayoutManager(manager);
    hexaRcv.setAdapter(new GridAdapter());
```

Below is the GridAdapter ()

```
public class GridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridAdapter.HexagonHolder> {
@Override
public GridAdapter.HexagonHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.hexa_tv, parent, false);
    return new HexagonHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(GridAdapter.HexagonHolder holder, int position) {
    int pos = position + 1;
    int topMargin = pxFromDp(holder.textView.getContext(), -17);
    int leftMargin = pxFromDp(holder.textView.getContext(), 51); //3 times of 17
    GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams param = (GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.textView.getLayoutParams();
    if (pos < 4) {
        param.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } else if ((pos + 1) % 5 == 0 || pos % 5 == 0) {
        param.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, 0, 0);
    } else {
        param.setMargins(0, topMargin, 0, 0);
    }
    holder.textView.setLayoutParams(param);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 17;
}

static class HexagonHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;

    HexagonHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        textView = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_1);
    }
}

private int pxFromDp(final Context context, final float dp) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

}

for first 3 items no margin. After that all item will have a negative top margin of 75 (i.e. -75px). every 4th and 5th item will not only have top margin of -75 but will also have a left margin of 165.

You can use constant or actually calculate them based on screen width or use dip.

Below is the result [image]

Below is the hexagon.xml save it in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="512dp"
    android:height="512dp"
    android:viewportWidth="512"
    android:viewportHeight="512">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#148275"
        android:pathData="M485.291,129.408l-224-128c-3.285-1.877-7.296-1.877-10.581,0l-224,128c-3.328,1.899-5.376,5.44-5.376,9.259v234.667
c0,3.819,2.048,7.36,5.376,9.259l224,128c1.643,0.939,3.456,1.408,5.291,1.408s3.648-0.469,5.291-1.408l224-128
c3.328-1.899,5.376-5.44,5.376-9.259V138.667C490.667,134.848,488.619,131.307,485.291,129.408z" />
</vector>
```

Comment: Let me try it out first.

Comment: Where is the @drawable/hexagon can you kindly provide it.

Comment: @Arpan I have added the hexagon

Comment: I'm not use to with kotlin can you modify the code in java?

Comment: @Arpan changed the code to java, edited the answer itself

Comment: thanks and its working good only one issue is the 165 and -75 margin. how can i calculate this based on the users screen width ?

Comment: @Arpan I have updated the GridAdapter code to use DIP so it should work on different screens. Not tested myself though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165546/discussion-between-arpan-and-hemant-patel).

Comment: Wow that's a great one, how would I need to change it in order to make it an octagon shape and not hexagon?

Comment: how can we set like 2-1-2-1 like span count and manage accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that. It needs to be improved as the gap between the two lines is not constant depending on the screen size:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <include
        layout="@layout/partial_squared"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**partial_squared.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        layout="@layout/partial_first_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/partial_second_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/line_height_80" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**partial_first_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView style="@style/InlinedImageView" />

        <ImageView style="@style/InlinedImageView" />

        <ImageView style="@style/InlinedImageView" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            style="@style/InlinedTextView"
            android:text="case 1" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/InlinedTextView"
            android:text="case 2" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/InlinedTextView"
            android:text="case 3" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**partial_second_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5" />

        <ImageView style="@style/InlinedImageView" />

        <ImageView style="@style/InlinedImageView" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/InlinedTextView"
            android:text="case 1" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/InlinedTextView"
            android:text="case 2" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**dimens.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="line_height">110dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="line_height_80">72dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_in_between">2dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="InlinedImageView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/line_height</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/triangle</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/margin_in_between</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/margin_in_between</item>
</style>

<style name="InlinedTextView">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
</style>
```

**Result**

[image]